# Not being prompted to download CSV file

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, mediatemple

I've created a custom solution in WordPress that will generate a CSV file to be downloaded by clicking a simple hyperlink, linked directly to this file. Instead of being prompted to download the file to the computer; the CSV opens in the the browser window instead.

FWIW I'm on Media Temple using a vanilla install of WordPress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the proper mime type

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
```

And use the Content-Disposition header to tell it to download: http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mycssfile.csv"');
```

You always want to send the proper mime type, otherwise firewalls, anti-virus software and some browsers may have issues with it...

Comment: Worked great! Thanks for the resource link as well!

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's `header()` function to change Content-type

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myFile.csv"');
```

The above code will force a prompt to the user for download. where `myFile.csv` should be replaced with the path to the file you want downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$filename = 'export.csv';
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```

Also, I personally do not like links on my sites, I like buttons.  If you want a button to do for the export function you can use the code below.  I just thought I would post it because it took me a bit to figure out the first time :)

```
<input type="button" value="Export to CSV" onClick="window.location.href='something.php?action=your_action';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the browser a MIME type of `application/csv` so it will offload the responsibility of handling the file to whatever the OS recommends (or user chooses).

In PHP (before any output is sent to the client):

```
header('Content-type: application/csv');
```