# Download .csv with Play! framework

Tags: csv, download, playframework-2.0

**EDIT**

From what I have learned (from comments by nico_ekito) it is not possible to use ajax call to download a file. The solution is to create a hidden `<iframe>` that will download the file, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676348/allow-user-to-download-file-using-ajax).

---

**Problem**:
The browser doesn't show download dialog. Any browser - ff, opera, chrome, safari, ie.

I read the [docs](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaStream) about serving files, found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868225/not-being-prompted-to-download-csv-file) and, based on this, wrote:

```
Controller.response().setContentType("text/csv");
Controller.response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=public/export/filename.csv");
Controller.response().setHeader("Cache-control", "private");

return ok(CSV.export(data, filename));
```

Where `CSV` is a class:

```
public class CSV{
    public static File export(Map<String, String> data, String filename){
        String csv = data.get("data[saveMe]");

        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("public/export/" + filename), "UTF-8"));
            bw.write(csv);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){}
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
        catch(IOException e){}

        File downloadMe = new File("public/export/" + filename);

        return downloadMe;
    }
}
```

On client side, I use `dojo` to send `POST` request (I also tried with `GET`, result is the same):

```
xhr.post({
    url: '/exportData/',
    content: {
        saveMe: str
    }
}).then(function(response){
    //do sth 
});
```

Response headers look like that:

```
Cache-Control       private
Content-Disposition attachment;filename=public/export/filename.csv
Content-Type        text/csv
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

`POST` tab in firebug shows proper data in proper csv format. To format data with csv style I use [dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/exporter/CSVWriter](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Exporter.html#prerequisites)

Comment: Have you tried using a GET request instead of a POST ?

Comment: thanks for the input, but `GET` doesn't work too

Comment: Why are you using Ajax and not a simple GET throuh a HTML link ?

Comment: @h4b0 if you play the url localhost:9000/exportData/?saveMe=test  , do you have something in your browser?

Comment: @Davz it works fine, nothing is shown in browser window, but I can see download dialog

Comment: @nico_ekito what do you mean?

Comment: I think that you don't need to use Ajax to perform the file download, just use a `<a href="@PATH_TO_YOUR_CONTROLLER">` link.

Comment: I need to send csv-formatted data to the server, I believe ajax is simpler solution in this case.

Comment: I think it is not possible, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676348/allow-user-to-download-file-using-ajax

Comment: I use ajax to send data to server, playframework is there to create file and send it back to client. But I start to believe you're right -  I'll fix my code to use a hidden `<iframe>`, as suggested in question you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible to download a file from an Ajax request, see this question: [Allow User to Download File using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676348/allow-user-to-download-file-using-ajax)

You should either use an iframe as suggested in the question, or use a standard HTML form containing your data, and do a post on this form.

Comment: `dojo.io.iframe` is the proper solution in this case, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570559/dojo-io-iframe-and-download-of-excel-pdf).